# How to put this GROK pattern to logstash.conf file?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I wrote a grok pattern using grok debugger for SAP logs but I don't know to use it in the Logstash configuration:

**Grok pattern:**

```
(?<AUDIt_LOG>[(0-9A-U]{0,4})(?<DATE>[0-9A-F]{8})%{INT:Log_Code}(?<Type>[a-zA-Z]{0,5})%{NOTSPACE:ServiceName} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE:Host} %{SPACE} %{WORD:Bank}&&%{WORD:BANK2}%{SPACE} %{WORD:USERNAME}
```

How do I use the grok filter to parse my log message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this between your input plugin and output plugin in your logstash.conf file

```
filter {
    grok {
         match => {
             "message" => "([(0-9A-U]{0,4})([0-9A-F]{8})%{INT:Log_Code}([a-zA-Z]{0,5})%{NOTSPACE:ServiceName}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:Host}%{SPACE}%{WORD:Bank}&&%{WORD:BANK2}%{SPACE}%{WORD:USERNAME}"
         }
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match) for additional explanation.

**UPDATE:**

There was some space on grok pattern.

Input

```
2AUK20170407183522001768800000D0itzpiascECCSERVICE SAPMSSY1 3001EDIN&&IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS itzpiascs
```

Output

```
ServiceName 0itzpiascECCSERVICE
Log_Code    183522001768800000
BANK2       IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS
USERNAME    itzpiascs
Bank        3001EDIN
Host        SAPMSSY1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: else if "2AU" in [message]{
    grok {
         match => {
             "message" => "(?[(0-9A-U]{0,4})(?[0-9A-F]{8})%{INT:Log_Code}(?[a-zA-Z]{0,5})%{NOTSPACE:ServiceName} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE:Host} %{SPACE} %{WORD:Bank}&&%{WORD:BANK2}%{SPACE} %{WORD:USERNAME}"
         }
    }
}

Comment: Well, it is not working because your grok pattern is having with (?. See this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-with-config/902. I don't know what you trying to do but see the update that I did. If you could provide some sample logs, then I will be of additional help.

Comment: This is sample log--->>> 2AUK20170407183522001768800000D0itzpiascECCSERVICE                      SAPMSSY1                                3001EDIN&&IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS                                 itzpiascs

Comment: Ok, I have done some update. I tested that on http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match. Please see the update.